# Android Programming: Long time delays in programming. Time

Tags: android, multithreading, date, time, delay

In my application I want to implement a way the user can set when they want a function to execute e.g. send a text message. They will in the form of date and time.

How can I implement this in android/java/other programming language?

Is there a better way to do it than just running a thread comparing the current date to the one set, and executing the function if the dates are the same ?

Comment: First have some trials with code for this and post this if you are facing some issues anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For tasks for which the user can give you a specific time and date, you can use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to have your task executed at that time.

This way, your app does not need to be running the whole time, and will be launched by Android when the time comes.